# Django Form exclude a field in form.as_div()

Tags: django, forms

Hi I am trying to register a user with address. I am trying to generate form with http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/

```
# models.py
class Address(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
    line_1      = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
# forms.py
class AddressForm(NgFormValidationMixin, Bootstrap3FormMixin, NgModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('line_1','city', 'state', 'user')
        # exclude = ('user',)  #this line
# views.py
class Register(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ...
        if userform.is_valid():
            user = userform.save()
            address = request.data['address']
            address['user'] = user.id
            addressform = AddressForm(address)
            if addressform.is_valid():
                addressform.save()  # gives error here if I add exclude('user', ) in form
            # else
                # revert the changes
        # else
            # revert the changes
```

If I generate form as 
`AddressForm().as_div()` it fetches all the user detail and it is available as dropdown to a registering user. (Big No)

So I add `exclude = ('user',)` to the form. Then AddressForm gives error in my view saying, `IntegrityError: accounts_address.user_id may not be NULL`

How to use same form in template & view?

Comment: why would you include `'user'` in `fields` and then exclude it? just remove it from `fields` if you don't want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `form.as_div()`, or with "using the same form in template and view".

If you exclude a field, adding it to the form data will have no effect, precisely because you've explicitly excluded it. Rather than saving one form and putting the result into the data to instantiate the second, you should just instantiate them both from the POST data, but use `commit=False` on the address form save to get an object you can manipulate before saving to the db.

```
def post(self, request):
    ...
    if userform.is_valid() and addressform.is_valid():
        user = userform.save()
        address = addressform.save(commit=False)
        address.user = user
        address.save()
        ...
```

This way you also don't need to worry about rolling back changes.